# Generate a unique identifier string with Visual Studio 2012

Tags: vb.net

I am creating a program with VS2012 that I need to generate a unique identification string.  I would like to be able to actually see the string and know some things about it:

1. whether it was created in the AM or PM
2. the month it was created
3. the day it was created
4. the hour it was created
5. the minute it was created

All of the above is VERY EASY for me:

```
Private Function GenIdentifier() As String
    
    GenIdentifier = Nothing

    Dim Part1 As String = IIf(Format(Now, "ttttt") = "AM", "A", "P")
    Dim Part2 As String = Format(Now, "MM")
    Dim Part3 As String = Format(Now, "dd")
    Dim Part4 As String = Format(Now, "hh")
    Dim Part5 As String = Format(Now, "mm")

    GenIdentifier = Part1 & Part2 & Part3 & Part4 & Part5

 End Function
```

The part I am having trouble with is that I am repeatedly calling this function.  I need to "add" to this another field that makes this string unique each time it is called.  What is the best way to do this?

Comment: See https://www.techrepublic.com/article/generating-guids-with-vbnet/

Comment: `dim n as long = 0 {loop} dim s = Date.Now.ToString("ttMMddhhmm") & $"{0,16:0000000000000000}{n+=1}"` -- 
`dim s = Date.Now.ToString("ttMMddhhmm") & Guid.NewGuid()`

Comment: Do you mean you want to create a custom component that preload this value when it is being called? Say like a text box or label that defaults to this value

Comment: Yat - Yes!  This is actually for a puzzle program I created.  This allows the user (player) to save the puzzle before completion and come back to it.  It also allows the user to save the puzzle in another format.  Jimi - Can you please reformat your answer.  I don't understand.  What is the "{loop}" for?

Comment: *[...] I am repeatedly calling this function [...]*: that's your loop.

Comment: Jimi, you have two (2) s Dim's.  Did you mean to use one or the other?  I am confused. What do these do?" I got an error when I tried to add the second one: Operator '&' is not defined for types 'String' and 'System.Guid'

Comment: Jimi, never mind!  I now understand that you were trying to complete the entire issue with either "s" line.  Thank you. .Close this issue

Comment: Those are two possible ways to have a string that is unique in a defined context, using parts of the current Date/Time. The first one formats a sequential `long` value, the other adds a Guid as a string to the formatted Date/Time.